# Change the red border between windows in xmonad

Tags: xmonad

Is it possible to set somewhere in configuration the color of the border between windows from red to black or remove the border completely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To change the colour, you can set `normalBorderColor` and `focusedBorderColor` in `xmonad.hs`. They should be set to `#RRGGBB`. For example, to set the focused window's border to black, set `focusedBorderColor = "#000000"`. The default color is `#FF0000`.

To disable the border, set `borderWidth = 0` in `xmonad.hs`, or use [`XMonad.Layout.NoBorders`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) for specific layouts.