# Toggle border with key combination in xmonad

Tags: xmonad

How can I define a key combination which toggles between my default borderwidth (for example 2) and disabled borders (borderwidth=0) in xmonad. Compare this related question: [Change the red border between windows in xmonad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21239/5289)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the [`XMonad.Actions.NoBorders`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/0.10/doc/html/XMonad-Actions-NoBorders.html) module (in `xmonad-contrib`) is helpful here (*I've not tried it myself, tough***<sup>(a)</sup>**).  It exports the `toggleBorder` function, which

> [toggles] the border of the currently focused window.

It's [rather small and self-explanatory](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/0.10/doc/html/src/XMonad-Actions-NoBorders.html#toggleBorder), so if binding `toggleBorder` doesn't do exactly what you want, you can probably adapt it to your needs.

**(a)** I'm not sure what you're about to achieve, but if you'd prefer not to have to press a key at all, the [`XMonad.Layout.NoBorders`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/0.10/doc/html/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) module is great.  It exports the `smartBorders` *layout modifier* that removes the borders if it is not needed (if there's only one window and only one screen, for example).